# Is there a grammatical error in 'is known to the prominent figures'?

Tags: grammaticality

What is grammatical error in below given sentence?

> Our beloved Prime Minister is known to the prominent figures all over the world.

My book says there is no error in this sentence, but I think there should be 'for' in the place of 'to', because anybody is known 'for something' not 'to something'.

Comment: Changing ***to*** to ***for*** would be completely ungrammatical / nonsensical. You're ***known for*** the attributes or deeds that make people aware of your existence, but you're ***known to*** those people who are aware of your existence. The only non-idiomatic aspect of the cited text is that native speakers would almost never include ***the***, but it's not actually ungrammatical to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no error in the sentence.  Yes, *known for* is a standard phrase, but it does not mean the same thing as *known to*.

**known for X**: famous or widely recognized because of reason X
**known to X**: familiar to person X; person X knows him (In this context, at least.  It can mean slightly different things in other contexts.)

So the meaning is that our beloved Prime Minister is *familiar to prominent figures all over the world*,  not "our beloved Prime Minister is widely known because of the reason of 'prominent figures all over the world'" (which doesn't even really make sense).

Comment: You might want to address the inclusion, in the original, of *"the"* ("to ***the*** prominent individuals"). You've excluded it in your answer, without explanation.